# Как прописать свой jar файл для компиляции в build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Есть проект, через командную строку и eclipse запускается и работает. В нём присутствует лишь один собственно созданный jar файл. Как прописать compile в конфиге билда? Или подскажите способ правильного "подключения" данного файла, для сборки jar.

```
apply plugin:'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile
}

jar {
baseName = 'jar-gradle'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В нём присутствует лишь один собственно созданный jar файл

Не понятно, что за jar-файл Вы имеете в виду. Если речь идет о подключении зависимости в виде jar-файла не из репозиториев, а прямо из локальной папки, то:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Здесь подразумевается, что в каталоге проекта есть папка lib, куда Вы положили все jar-файлы зависимостей.

Comment: Да, прямо из локальной папки, прописал как у вас зависимости, кидает ошибку  Build Failed with an exeption. A problem was found with the configuration of task ' startscripts'. No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'

Comment: startScripts - это task плагина application. Он предназначен для сборки "дистрибутива" вашего приложения и генерации скриптов запуска. Если не знаете, зачем Вам всё это нужно - уберите строчку apply plugin: 'application'. Иначе укажите требуемые параметры - в частности, точку входа (mainClassName).

Comment: Спасибо, заработало